# How would a militaristic society that viewed the laws of war sacred develop?

Tags: society, worldbuilding-process, law, military

While different nations have different laws of war, this society has laws of war similar to those followed by the United States Armed Forces; how would a militaristic society develop that saw its laws of war as sacred?

Technology level is similar to our 21st century military technology (with some advanced technology like lasers but they're like experimental prototypes).

Also this society has been around for many years.

For example:

This society sees the usage of chemical, biological, and nuclear weapons as paramount to war crimes (the usage of nuclear weapons is only to be used as a last and final result and when all other options are exhausted).

Prisoners of war are treated with respect and the usage of enhanced interrogation (aka torture) is refrained from (except in the most dire of circumstances).

Deliberate killing of civilians without cause is punishable by the death penalty. This also applies to the enemy.  Enemy commanders who have committed this act are shot on sight. Children are never to be harmed (if enemy commanders have forced children to act as soldiers, then said enemy commanders are to be shot on sight). Enemy soldiers who have conducted said mistreatment of civilians will be investigated and if found guilty by their own free will shall be executed. Those who were forced to harm civilians against their will shall be imprisoned and treated as 'forced combatants' and be reconditioned if necessary.

Assisting civilians and even wounded enemy combatants is praised and those who performed such deeds are highly regarded by society.

A clear declaration of war must be given.

Looting and plundering of historical areas is considered a war crime and usually results in court-martial and extensive jail time.  Destruction of historical areas and items faces the same punishment (although execution will be added if civilians are harmed during the destruction of said historical items and areas).

Comment: One imagines they would be eventually exterminated by some other society with a more flexible system of values.

Comment: Without some more background this is almost unanswerable.  What is the technology level of the society (some existing rules of war cannot be adhered to or are meaningless without modern technology eg prohibitions on blinding lasers)? How long has the society been around? What are the actual laws of war that the society regards as sacred?

Comment: I added some additional info Kerr.

Comment: You need more information, not everyone is intimately familiar with US military policy.

Comment: And that is a bit too much? Could you condense them into some bullet points the most significant and telling laws? Or summarize into a managable length?

Comment: @SCPilot Whildt references are on the whole a good idea, I am most emphatically **not** reading a thousand page document, I doubt that many will. Bear in mind that links become broken with time and we need this to be a clear question in years to come for people's reference. (From review)

Comment: Can you please give an example of a country which actually practices or practiced such silly chivalry? My immediate reaction is that it cannot possibly be around for that many years.

Comment: Well Alex I mean America has practiced or tried to practice such chivalry at times.  :D

And since this is a fictional society, I don't know if I could give an example of such a country.

Comment: This is in the VTR queue, but it's too broad.  Entire books are written about the development of civilizations.  The [help/on-topic] explains that questions must be specific and answerable, must include context, must include restrictions/requirements, and should include research.  Can you [edit] this Q down to a specific problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Actual Religion:**

The members of this society have a holy book which has its followers fight regularly, but which stipulates several rules of war. Deviating from the rules is deviating from the religion, and is impiety. Anyone who does such a thing is excommunicated, banished, or killed, depending on the other rules of the society.

**Past Horrors:**

This society has seen done, had done to them, and done themselves such horrible things under the name of war, that they decided to make rules that forbid all such horrendous acts and hold the laws sacred. This could be done by a religious group, but it could also be influential leaders, or a large group of upright citizens. As this would be a set of laws, there would also be punishments for lawbreakers, e.g. going to jail.

**Whole World:**

Every other group/country in the world follows the same laws. Obviously, there would be retribution for any group/country who broke the laws, whether they are unspoken or not. Actually, it wouldn't have to be *every single* other group/country in the world. There could be something like the United Nations, where many of the largest and most powerful countries in the world, though not all, participate in an *entente* to abide by laws prohibiting certain acts in war. Of course, any group/country in the union who refused to comply under any circumstances would be punished, perhaps in a similar way to how countries are punished in the United Nations, with sanctions or other such methods.